# Float div to the right for all screen sizes

Tags: css, html

so the header on my site looks alright when I view it on my laptop. but on the 27'' mac, the div that should be floating right appears in the middle of the screen.  any suggestions?

The CSS:

```
    #facebook {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'discoregular' ;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right:0px;
    right:0;
}
```

[the site](http://emmaferreira.com)

Comment: Inspect your header, it has 1024px width and is floated left, how is the span that is nested inside it supposed to go to the screen's right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should place

```
<span id="facebook">
```

outside of

```
<div id="Menu" class="span2">
```

so it can float to the right of the window.

Comment: okay that works, but now, the content of the page displays wayy down below the menu instead of next to it.